# Turn Constant Expression into a Type

Tags: templates, c++11, non-type

For a declarative defined part of a [system](https://github.com/TorstenRobitzki/bluetoe), some handlers* have to be passed as types:

```
int read_handler();
class handler {...};

typedef bluetoe::service<
    bluetoe::service_uuid< 0x8C8B4094, 0x0DE2, 0x499F, 0xA28A, 0x4EED5BC73CA9 >,
    bluetoe::characteristic<
        bluetoe::free_read_handler< read_handler >,                                // *
        bluetoe::member_read_handler< handler, &handler::read, &handler_instance > // *
    >
> service;
```

Especially for the member function version, this "value to type"-conversion have to be defined for every cv qualifier combination. And for every conversion I have to introduce a new name.

So I'm looking for a way to unify this, without scarifying, the zero memory size property (so std::function is not an option). What I've tried, was to deduce the type and capture the value of a handler by a constexpr function. Something along the line:

```
typedef bluetoe::service<
    bluetoe::service_uuid< 0x8C8B4094, 0x0DE2, 0x499F, 0xA28A, 0x4EED5BC73CA9 >,
    bluetoe::characteristic<
        decltype( bluetoe::bind( read_handler ) ),
        decltype( bluetoe::bind( handler, &handler::read, &handler_instance ) )
    >
> service;
```

with `bind` being:

```
auto constexpr bind( void(*f)() ) -> bluetoe::free_read_handler< f > 
{
    return bluetoe::free_read_handler< f >();
}
```

Can someone of you think about a solution to make this work. Preferable with C++11, but any solution that, at least simplifies the task is welcome too.

Comment: Can't use function arguments for this - they are never constant expressions. Overloaded function templates may work.

Comment: But in a `constexpr` function, function arguments should be constant expressions. That's the trick I try to explore ;-)